# Grothendieck's 1955 paper: general theory of fibre spaces ...

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

I would very much appreciate any pdf [in french, or english(!)] of Grothendieck's 1955 paper 'A general theory of fibre spaces with structure sheaf' ... I've tried a full search, but no luck yet, and no access. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could provide more complete bibliographic details.

Comment: [Here](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/Kansasnotes.pdf) is a link and a project of [translation](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/Kansasnotes-French.pdf) to French

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here you go.](http://library1.org/_ads/1B54609888AD41F954973D4F9E860C53) I just tested the download. It's a djvu file, so you may want to convert to pdf if you don't have a suitable reader.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a scan [A general theory of fibre spaces with structure sheaf](https://agrothendieck.github.io/divers/kansasscan.pdf)

There is an ongoing translation here [Une théorie générale des espaces fibrés
à structure de faisceaux](http://cm2vivi2002.free.fr/AG-biblio/transc-AG-fibres-1et2-fr.pdf)